# Problems with sharing Unity Projects using Github From Windows to macOS

Tags: windows, git, macos, unity-game-engine, github

So me and my team started to develop a game using Unity3D.  We wanted to share the project using Github so we can be up-to-date with each other's modifications.

I successfully pushed my Unity project (the whole project folder) to Github with a .gitignore (attached below) and also the meta files. I also allowed Force Text and Visible Meta Files.

I am using Windows 10 and my teammate is using macOS. The problem starts when my teammate tries pulling from the repository, he gets the files but when he opens the project, some of the objects in the Hierarchy Tab are invisible and all that he sees in the scene are some cubes and spheres and nothing else.

I am using FullStackForger's .gitignore (Thanks btw).  Link here 
https://gist.github.com/FullStackForger/20bbf62861394b1a3de0

Comment: This might be a case of text files being treated as binary, or binary files being treated as text files breaking them (CR-LF handling).  I would suggest you look into the actual byte content of the files and compare across platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the EOL (end of line) style of the file is correct, and that each developper has configured:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That way, you are sure Git will not modifiy automatically on checkout those files.